# Uber sandbox hook "arriving" status bug

Tags: sandbox, uber-api

I got a strange bug during testing: changing trip statuses via uber api (sandbox).

When I send "arriving" status, on server I got two hooks:

- one is correct (with "arriving" status)
- another one is incorrect (with "completed" status)

Does anyone have the same issue?